# Does the number of subscribers influence the receiving time in MQTT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, messagebroker

I want to know that the number of subscribers to a specific topic cause delay in receiving messages in each subscriber or not?
If yes, is it related to the implementation of the broker or it is the nature of MQTT?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation of various brokers or maybe I couldn't find a right term to search for.

```
scenario 1 :
topic1
publisher --> broker --> 1 subscriber

scenario 2 :
topic1
publisher --> broker --> 2 or more subscribers
```

Will message be received in subscriber in scenario 1 faster than scenario 2?
or each subscriber receive the message at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will mainly depend on how the broker is implemented, but other factors will also have an influence.

For most brokers the handling of delivering a specific message is likely to be single threaded and follow these steps:

- Broker receives publish packet from the publishing client
- On the thread that receives the message it starts to search the list of subscribed topic patterns of the connected clients
- On finding a match it will send the publish packet to that client and move on to the next one.

With a well designed subscription topic tree structure then the search time shouldn't change depending on the number of subscribed clients, just the number of matching patterns (overlapping wildcards). But the sending to the matching clients will be linear.

The other factor is going to be the size of the message and the speed of the network to each client.

You can probably parallelise a some of this, either in a single broker but this will still bottle neck on the network interface or across a distributed broker (but that will add overhead of pushing the original message to the other nodes)

Comment: first thanks for your answer.
"With a well designed subscription topic tree structure then the search time shouldn't change depending on the number of subscribed clients, just the number of matching patterns (overlapping wildcards)"   

if I understood correctly, you mean using wildcards can cause delay too?     

my publishers are sending to topics like this : factory/gw/sensor/datatype
 - gw ,sensor and datatype are dynamic.

my two or more subscribers are subscribed to factory/# to receive all data   
   
this pattern factory/# cause delay too?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that there may be multiple possible topic patterns that will match the message. e.g. `factory/gw/sensor/datatype` will be matched by `#`, `factory/#`, `+/gw/sensor/datatype` plus a lot more possible combinations and matching the different wildcard topics **may** lead to some clients receiving the message **slightly** later than others. Again it all depends on how the broker is implemented

Comment: This will only be answered in a performance testing investigation, eg. as detailed at https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2019/01/200000-mqtt-connections-to-ibm.html